# Jmeter - How to test an api protected with Client Certificate Authentication in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

How to test an api protected with Client Certificate Authentication in Jmeter?
Client Certificate Authentication - How to get an alias for the certificate?
Can someone please help me with the configuration in Jmeter that can do the same..

Comment: How can I do the same in Blazemeter??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the certificate (and the client file) into a jks (or better pkcs12) [keystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore), I normally do this using [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) command line tool and [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) but you might find a GUI-based tool like [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) easier

If you need to supply only one certificate - it would be sufficient just to provide keystore location, type and password to JMeter via `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`, `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` system properties correspondingly.

If you have > 1 certificate in the keystore and would like each JMeter thread to use different certificate - go for [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) element

Check out [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites/) article for more details.

Comment: Thank you Dimitri. Can you please help me on the same using blazemeter?

Comment: Just upload `system.properties` file and keystore along with your .jmx script and BlazeMeter systems will pick it up. If you're a BlazeMeter customer you can reach out to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-open-a-support-ticket-), they know their infrastructure much better than anyone here.